# I'm having difficulties in manipulating records from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I'm having difficulties in retrieving and displaying records from a table in a database. I'm using a MySql database and VB.NET 2012.

I'm getting the following error message

> "End of statement expected"

[image]

Comment: Don't post images but text and describe your issue

Comment: Remove the space between `Form2` and `_Load`.

Comment: Your SQL String is broken, the `AND ` is not part of it and is being interpreted as a VB `And`.  It also makes no sense as the value cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time, perhaps you mean `"... where regid=1 or regid=2"`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between `Form2` and `_Load`. Your SQL statement is also broken, the AND being in blue shows this. You have your single and double quotes confusing it, the statement is being ended before the AND due to incorrect syntax. In any case, you should, probably, be using

```
"SELECT * FROM bigregdb WHERE regID = '"1"' OR regID = '"2"'"
```